# What are the correct specs of Tecno W3 smart phone?

Tags: hardware, gpu, tech-specs

I would like to by Tecno W3 smart phone (Android 6.0 Marshmallow).

I googled to know its GPU. Some websites said it's **Mali-400 GPU** such as:

1. http://bestmobs.com/tecno-w3/
2. http://naijaquest.com/tecno-w3-specs-features-reviews-and-price-official/

And other websites said it's **Mali-400MP2 GPU** such as:

1. http://www.androidphonesinnigeria.com/tecno-w3-full-specifications-features-price/
2. http://www.droidafrica.com/tecno-w3-brings-android-60/

The official website of the phone does not give any information about the GPU nor the part number of the CPU IC.

How can I know the real GPU when I test the phone at the shop? Is there an android test code? Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test it with [CPU-Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z) when you're in store and permitted to access the device.

Comment: When and how can CPU-Z detect the core count of GPU?

Comment: @iBug One can infer the GPU from the SoC model itself. It's not like the phone will use an SoC that's off the charts or specially made...

Comment: That's indirect. A straightforward solution is better.

Comment: @iBug Well, what you posted is also doing such inference...

Comment: I'm going to take out the inference and give a direct instruction.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** If your model supports 4G LTE, then its GPU is **Mali-400 MP2**. If it has no 4G support, its GPU is **Mali-400 MP** (single core).

I noticed that there might be **2 different models** of that phone. Older one (doesn't support 4G cellular network) uses MediaTek MT6572, while newer one (4G cellular) uses MT6582.

Both MT6572 and MT6582 have ARM Mali-400 GPU built in. MT6572 has only one GPU core, thus called **Mali-400 MP**. MT6582 has 2 cores built, so it's called Mali-400 **MP2**.

ARM **Mali-400** is the **name** of the core (and architecture), while **MP2** states that there are 2 Mali-400 cores. So in all, **Mali-400 MP2** is a specific configuration of Mali-400.

The two different statement do not conflict with each other, only the first one not telling how many cores there is.

Comment: +1: Much more detailed info than mine. Mind sharing where you found out the exact SoC the phone is using? I've been using PDAdb but it doesn't include the least popular devices like this one in question.

Comment: @AndyYan "Tecno W3" has an MT6572, whereas "Tecno W3-**H806**" has an MT6582. I couldn't find the model number of the MT6572 model.